# bilinear functional on complex vector space

Tags: linear-algebra

Given a complex vector space S, if g: S $\times$ S $\rightarrow$ $\mathbb{C}$ is a symmetric bilinear functional, can we say there always exist v $\in$ S and w $\in$ S such that g(v,w) = 0?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Yes.  Just take either $v$ or $w$, or even both, to be the zero vector.

Comment: wait,I mean for non-zero v and w...

Comment: I see.  You are looking for the condition called *degeneracy* for the bilinear form: see [degenerate bilinear form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degenerate_bilinear_form).  There surely exist degenerate bilinear forms, but there are also nondegenerate ones.

If the bilinear form in question defines a [scalar product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product) (over the complex field, it can't be symmetric), and if $S$ has dimension 2 or higher, you can pick any nonzero $v$, and pick a nonzero $w$ from the [orthogonal complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonal_complement) of $v$.

Comment: Thanks actually, I try to solve a problem on symmetric bilinear form. the question is on " can we find a base of S, say s_1,....s_n such that g(s_i, s_j ) = 0 for i $\neq$ j, g(s_i, s_i) = 1 for 1 $\leq$ i $\leq$ t, and g(s_i, s_i) = 0 for t+1 $\leq$ i $\leq$ n

Comment: Ok.  For a fixed vector $v$, the mapping that sends the vector $w$ to $g(u, w)$
$$
w \mapsto g(u, w)
$$
is a [linear functional](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_form) on $S$.  If $S$ has dimension 2 or higher, then this functional has a nontrivial kernel.  Any $w$ from that kernel will satisfy
$$
g(u, w) = 0,
$$
by the very definition of *kernel*.

Comment: Can I know why " if S has dimension 2 or higher, then the functional has a non trivial kernel. " ?  Is non-trivial kernel equivalent to non-empty kernel?

Comment: "Trivial kernel" = "kernel that equals to the zero subspace"

As for the other question: if a linear functional on a vector space $V$ is not identically zero, then the kernel of the functional has dimension that's one less than that of $V$ (by the rank-nullity theorem).

Comment: okay. But how can we relate it with the above question? I mean " can we find a base of S, say s_1,....s_n such that g(s_i, s_j ) = 0 for i ≠ j; g(s_i, s_i) = 1 for 1 $\leq$ i $\leq$ t;  g(s_i, s_i) = 0 for t+1 $\leq$ i $\leq$ n?"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/92916/discussion-between-avs-and-jonny).